# How do I find the number of unique permutations for a PERMANOVA with an unbalanced design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test, ecology, vegan

From the PRIMER manual (p. 28 about Monte Carlo permutations; http://updates.primer-e.com/primer7/manuals/PERMANOVA+_manual.pdf), the number of unique permutations for a PERMANOVA with $a$ groups and $n$ replicates per group is:
$$
(an)![a!(n!)^a].
$$
However, what is the calculation if the study design is unbalanced? For example, one group with $4$ individuals, another with $5$, another with $6$? Is there a way to calculate the number of unique permutations with `adonis2`?

---

Thank you for pointing numPerms(). However, I am getting an incorrect answer, even with simpler examples.

```
# Create 2 groups of 5. 
myVec = c(rep("A",5), rep("B", 5))

# Define the permutation scheme. 
hh = how(within = Within(type = "free"),
          blocks = as.factor(myVec))

# Calculate number of permutations
numPerms(nobs(myVec), hh)
```

However, 2 groups of 5 should have 945 unique permutations, but this returns 14400. What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is a special case of the general answer I gave at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/415878/919.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, but I'm not sure if I know how to solve it for this case. Following your equations, what would the values be for k?

Answer (score 0):

Function `permute::numPerms` calculates the number of permutations for your current model. The permutations in `vegan::adonis2` are based on this very same **permute** package, and if you have specific problems with permutations, you should consult the **permute** package. Use `numPerms()` and read its help page.