# How do you use numPerms to get the total number of unique permutations for a PERMANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test, ecology, vegan, permutation

I am trying to calculate the number of unique permutations for a PERMANOVA using the R `adonis2` function but I am getting stuck on defining my permutation scheme.

As suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601010/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-unique-permutations-for-a-permanova-with-an-unbalanc) I am using the `numPerms` function from the `permute` package to get the answer. However, I am getting stuck with how it works, even in simpler designs. Here is an example with an attempt:

```
# Create sample dataframe with counts for 3 species from 10 different locations
# Counts are randomly generated from 1-100
set.seed(2)
df = data.frame(
  sp1 = sample(1:100, 10),
  sp2 = sample(1:100, 10),
  sp3 = sample(1:100, 10)
)

# Create a vector of data with 2 groups of 5. 
myGroups = c(rep("A",5), rep("B", 5))

# Define the permutation scheme. 
hh = how(blocks = as.factor(myGroups))

# My PERMANOVA would therefore be as follows with the permutation scheme specified (I think?)
adonis2(df~myGroups, perm = hh)

# Calculate number of permutations
numPerms(df, hh)
```

However, $2$ groups of $5$ should have $126$ unique permutations (e.g., see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856568/how-many-ways-are-there-to-split-10-people-into-two-groups-of-5)), but this returns $14400$. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You did nothing wrong; {permute} doesn't know how to do permutations of the sort you want.

The permutation test you described via `how()` is a randomization test restricted by blocks, so there are 5! * 5! such permutations, which is what `numPerms()` returns.