Can my solution to a counting problem be corrected?
There was an interesting question in my stats class:
There are 5 scientists, 2 of which are Statisticians ($N_{a}$) and 3 are Biologists ($N_{b}$). How many ways can we choose 3 scientists, such that there are at least 1 Statistician ($R_a$) and 1 Biologist ($R_b$).
The method I proposed sounds reasonable at first and is far more elegant, but it's wrong. Interestingly though, I couldn't calculate by how much my method would over count. This suggests to me that my method is completely unrelated to the solution, but I'm unsure.
I wrote some python code to visualize what is going on and some patterns do arise, but I could not interpret them and its driving me crazy.
Variables




N
R




a
2
1


b
3
1



$$
\begin{align}
R_{total} &= 3 \\
R_{any} &= R_{total} - R_{a} - R_{b} \\
&= 3 - 1 - 1 = 1
\end{align}
$$
Solution (Correct)
$$
\begin{align}
n &= \sum^1_{i=0} {N_{a} \choose R_{a} + i}{N_{b} \choose R_{b} + R_{any} - i} \\
&= {2 \choose 1}{3 \choose 2} +  {2 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1} \\
&= 2 \times 3 + 1 \times 3 \\
&= 6 + 3 \\
&= 9
\end{align}
$$
My idea (wrong)
$$
\begin{align}
n &={N_{a} \choose R_{a}}{N_{b} \choose R_{b}}{N_{a} + N_{b} - (R_{a} + R_{b}) \choose R_{any}}\\
&={2 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} \\
&=2 \times 3 \times 3 \\
&=18
\end{align}
$$
My idea was:

Choose $R_{a}$ Statistician
Choose $R_{b}$ Biologist
Choose $R_{any}$ Scientist from the remaining pool

UPDATED QUESTION
Is there an $f$ such that:
$$
\begin{align}
{N_{a} \choose R_{a}}{N_{b} \choose R_{b}}{N_{a} + N_{b} - (R_{a} + R_{b}) \choose R_{any}} + f(N_{a}, N_{b}, R_{a}, R_{b}, R_{any}) = \sum_{i=0} {N_{a} \choose R_{a} + i}{N_{b} \choose R_{b} + R_{any} - i}
\end{align}
$$
I'm looking for a general solution using the above variables.
Extra - Visualization


Using: $N_{a}=3, N_{b}=3, R_{a}=2, R_{b}=1, R_{any}=1$
Python code
pip install xlsxwriter # install this if you want to generate the excel file

import json
import subprocess
import time
import warnings
from collections import Counter
from enum import IntEnum
from itertools import combinations
from math import factorial

import xlsxwriter

warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=UserWarning)

# TailwindCSS colors
using_colors = False
COLORS = {}
if using_colors:
    with open("colors2.json", "r") as f:
        COLORS = json.load(f)
        color_names = list(COLORS.keys())


def count_permutations(n, r):
    return factorial(n) / factorial(n - r)


def count_combinations(n, r):
    return count_permutations(n, r) / factorial(r)


ScientistType = IntEnum("ScientistType", ["Statistician", "Biologist"])


class GenerateSolutions:
    def __init__(self, n_sta, n_bio, r_sta, r_bio, r_total):
        self.n_sta = n_sta
        self.n_bio = n_bio
        self.r_sta = r_sta
        self.r_bio = r_bio
        self.r_total = r_total

        self.STA_IDX = list(range(self.n_sta))
        self.BIO_IDX = list(range(self.n_sta, self.n_sta + self.n_bio))

        self.SCI_IDX = self.STA_IDX + self.BIO_IDX
        self.scientist_types = [
            ScientistType.Statistician for _ in range(self.n_sta)
        ] + [ScientistType.Biologist for _ in range(self.n_bio)]

    @property
    def r_any(self):
        return self.r_total - (self.r_sta + self.r_bio)

    def method_x(self):
        s = 0
        for i in range(self.r_any + 1):
            c1 = 0
            if self.r_sta + i <= self.n_sta:
                c1 = count_combinations(self.n_sta, self.r_sta + i)
            c2 = 0
            if self.r_bio + self.r_any - i <= self.n_bio:
                c2 = count_combinations(self.n_bio, self.r_bio + self.r_any - i)
            s += c1 * c2
        return s

    def method_y(self):
        return (
            count_combinations(self.n_sta, self.r_sta)
            * count_combinations(self.n_bio, self.r_bio)
            * count_combinations(
                (self.n_sta + self.n_bio) - (self.r_sta + self.r_bio), self.r_any
            )
        )

    def is_valid_choice(self, perm):
        counter = Counter([self.scientist_types[sci_id] for sci_id in perm])
        return (
            counter[ScientistType.Statistician] >= self.r_sta
            and counter[ScientistType.Biologist] >= self.r_bio
        )

    def method_y_sanity_check(self):
        perms = combinations(self.SCI_IDX, self.r_total)
        count = 0
        for perm in perms:
            if self.is_valid_choice(perm):
                count += 1
        return count

    def generate_combinations_y(self):
        options = {}
        all_opts = 0

        for S in combinations(self.STA_IDX, self.r_sta):
            for B in combinations(self.BIO_IDX, self.r_bio):
                selected_ids = S + B
                remaining_ids = [i for i in self.SCI_IDX if i not in selected_ids]
                for R in combinations(remaining_ids, self.r_any):
                    all_opts += 1
                    option = S + B + R
                    option_id = tuple(sorted(option))

                    if option_id not in options:
                        options[option_id] = []

                    options[option_id].append(option)

        print(f"All options: {all_opts}")

        return options

    def export_options(self, options):
        name = f"test_{time.time()}.xlsx"

        book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(name)
        sheet = book.add_worksheet()

        max_options = len(
            sorted(options.values(), key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)[0]
        )

        header = (
            [f"{i}_" for i in range(1, self.r_total + 1)]
            + ["STA_Count", "Bio_Count", "Combo_Count"]
            + [f"o_{i}" for i in range(1, max_options + 1)]
        )
        for i, h in enumerate(header):
            sheet.write(0, i, h, book.add_format({"bold": True}))

        for row, (id, combos) in enumerate(options.items()):
            for i, sci_id in enumerate(id):
                sheet.write(row + 1, i, sci_id)

            count_start_ord = 68 + self.r_total
            sheet.write(
                row + 1,
                self.r_total,
                f'=COUNTIF(A{row + 2}:{chr(count_start_ord - 4)}{row + 2}, "<{self.n_sta}")',
            )
            sheet.write(
                row + 1,
                self.r_total + 1,
                f'=COUNTIF(A{row + 2}:{chr(count_start_ord - 4)}{row + 2}, ">{self.n_sta - 1}")',
            )
            sheet.write(
                row + 1,
                self.r_total + 2,
                f"=COUNTA({chr(count_start_ord)}{row + 2}:{chr(count_start_ord + max_options - 1)}{row + 2})",
            )

            for i, combo in enumerate(combos):
                sheet.write(
                    row + 1, i + self.r_total + 3, "_".join([str(c) for c in combo])
                )

        sta_format = book.add_format({"color": "red"})
        bio_format = book.add_format({"color": "green"})

        if using_colors:
            for sci_1, sci_2 in combinations(self.SCI_IDX, 2):
                code = (sci_2 - self.n_bio + 4) * 100
                hex = list(COLORS[color_names[sci_1]].values())[sci_2 - self.n_bio + 2]

                sheet.conditional_format(
                    1,
                    self.r_total + 3,
                    len(options),
                    self.r_total + 3 + max_options,
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "criteria": "begins with",
                        "value": f"{sci_1}_{sci_2}",
                        "format": book.add_format(
                            {
                                "bg_color": hex,
                                "font_color": "#FFFFFF" if code > 500 else "#000000",
                            }
                        ),
                    },
                )

        sheet.conditional_format(
            1,
            0,
            len(options),
            self.r_total - 1,
            {
                "type": "cell",
                "criteria": "<",
                "value": self.BIO_IDX[0],
                "format": sta_format,
            },
        )
        sheet.conditional_format(
            1,
            0,
            len(options),
            self.r_total - 1,
            {
                "type": "cell",
                "criteria": ">",
                "value": self.STA_IDX[-1],
                "format": bio_format,
            },
        )

        book.close()

        print("Unique options:", len(options))

        return len(options)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = GenerateSolutions(n_sta=2, n_bio=3, r_sta=1, r_bio=1, r_total=3)

    options = model.generate_combinations_y()
    model.export_options(options)

colors.json (from TailwindCSS)
{
  "pink": {
    "200": "#fbcfe8",
    "300": "#f9a8d4",
    "400": "#f472b6",
    "500": "#ec4899",
    "600": "#db2777",
    "700": "#be185d",
    "800": "#9d174d",
    "900": "#831843"
  },
  "purple": {
    "200": "#e9d5ff",
    "300": "#d8b4fe",
    "400": "#c084fc",
    "500": "#a855f7",
    "600": "#9333ea",
    "700": "#7e22ce",
    "800": "#6b21a8",
    "900": "#581c87"
  },
  "indigo": {
    "200": "#c7d2fe",
    "300": "#a5b4fc",
    "400": "#818cf8",
    "500": "#6366f1",
    "600": "#4f46e5",
    "700": "#4338ca",
    "800": "#3730a3",
    "900": "#312e81"
  },
  "blue": {
    "200": "#bfdbfe",
    "300": "#93c5fd",
    "400": "#60a5fa",
    "500": "#3b82f6",
    "600": "#2563eb",
    "700": "#1d4ed8",
    "800": "#1e40af",
    "900": "#1e3a8a"
  },
  "green": {
    "200": "#bbf7d0",
    "300": "#86efac",
    "400": "#4ade80",
    "500": "#22c55e",
    "600": "#16a34a",
    "700": "#15803d",
    "800": "#166534",
    "900": "#14532d"
  },
  "teal": {
    "200": "#99f6e4",
    "300": "#5eead4",
    "400": "#2dd4bf",
    "500": "#14b8a6",
    "600": "#0d9488",
    "700": "#0f766e",
    "800": "#115e59",
    "900": "#134e4a"
  },
  "lime": {
    "200": "#d9f99d",
    "300": "#bef264",
    "400": "#a3e635",
    "500": "#84cc16",
    "600": "#65a30d",
    "700": "#4d7c0f",
    "800": "#3f6212",
    "900": "#365314"
  },
  "yellow": {
    "200": "#fef08a",
    "300": "#fde047",
    "400": "#facc15",
    "500": "#eab308",
    "600": "#ca8a04",
    "700": "#a16207",
    "800": "#854d0e",
    "900": "#713f12"
  },
  "orange": {
    "200": "#fed7aa",
    "300": "#fdba74",
    "400": "#fb923c",
    "500": "#f97316",
    "600": "#ea580c",
    "700": "#c2410c",
    "800": "#9a3412",
    "900": "#7c2d12"
  },
  "red": {
    "200": "#fecaca",
    "300": "#fca5a5",
    "400": "#f87171",
    "500": "#ef4444",
    "600": "#dc2626",
    "700": "#b91c1c",
    "800": "#991b1b",
    "900": "#7f1d1d"
  }
}


You are double-counting many choices.  The solution, $9,$ is so small that in a few moments you can enumerate all the distinct choices and compare them to what your solution is counting.

One of your $18$ is Statistician 1 from the statisticians and Biologist 4 from the biologists and Biologist 3 from the remaining three.  Another of your $18$ is Statistician 1 from the statisticians and Biologist 3 from the biologists and Biologist 4 from the remaining three.  But these are the same triplet.  In fact you have double counted every allowable triplet; the person from the "remaining three" with their previously chosen colleague to see this.

@whuber Thank you for your comment. Interestingly, after changing a few of the input variables, the double counting becomes inconsistent (see the 2nd screenshot I uploaded). I'm looking for a general solution to calculate the number of double counts

There are general solutions to counting problems like this.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/415878/919 for one broad set of solutions.  For more, read the first chapter on "The Twelvefold Way" in Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics.

As a hint, it often is the case in probabilities, that it is easier to look for the exact logical opposite of what you want (this simplifies the problem). In other words, instead of counting all the ways you can get what you want, count all the ways you would fail to get what you want. In your case (picking 3 out of 5), what you what to avoid is picking all 3 biologists; that is the only way you will not get at least 1 of each. So the number of "bad" outcomes is just 1. What is the total number of outcomes? $C^3_5$. So the answer is $C^3_5-1=\frac {5!} {3!2!}-1=\frac {20} {2}-1=9$.
Now, yes, you could also count the way to get what you want. YOu could get statistician 1, and any 2 biologists, or statistician 2, and any 2 biologists, or the 2 statisticians, and 1 of the 3 biologists. There is only 1 way to get statisticain 1, and 3 ways to get 2 of the 3 biologists ((B1, B2), (B1,B3), B2,B3); or $C_3^2=3$). Same for first getting statistician 2. And there is only 1 way to get the 2 statisticians, and 3 ways to get a single biologist. So in the end $3+3+3=9$. Or, morte "mathematically", $2.C_3^2+1.C_3^1=2.3+1.3=9$.
But the first approach seems (at least to me) simpler. And it is often the case for problems of combinatorics and/or probabilities (probably because instructors try to confuse students by creating some complexities). So take a step back, look at the exact logical opposite of what you are trying to count/estimate the probability of, and often (not always, but in a majority of cases for classrom/textbook exercises), that "opposite way" will be simpler.
